# Equivalence between Bayes Threshold and Neyman Pearson Threshold?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, hypothesis-testing

I could not find an answer to this question, so it's probably obvious to everyone else:

This question concerns binary hypothesis testing ($\mathcal{H}_{0}$ versus $\mathcal{H}_{1}$) against data $\mathbf{x}$. I would like to know if we can solve for a Neyman-Pearson (NP) threshold that is equivalent to a threshold that is given by a Bayes test that minimizes Risk under $0-1$ loss.

Disclaimer: I am not a mathematician or statistician.

Let us keep it simple and assume we know the PDF for $\mathbf{x}$ under both hypotheses (I will worry about GLRTs on my own). The the NP decision rule is:

\begin{equation}
 \cfrac{ f\left(\mathbf{x} \, \vert \, \mathcal{H}_{1} \right) } {f\left(\mathbf{x} \, \vert \, \mathcal{H}_{0} \right) }
\,\,
\underset{\mathcal{H}_{0}}
{ \overset{\mathcal{H}_{1}}
{\gtrless}}
\,\,
t,
\end{equation}

where $t$ is the threshold, $f\left(\mathbf{x} \, \vert \, \mathcal{H}_{1} \right)$ is the density for $\mathbf{x}$ under $\mathcal{H}_{1}$, and $f\left(\mathbf{x} \, \vert \, \mathcal{H}_{0} \right)$ is the density for $\mathbf{x}$ under $\mathcal{H}_{0}$. If we set threshold $t$ for a fixed false alarm probability $\text{Pr}_{FA} = \alpha$ as consistent with the NP criterion, then:

\begin{equation}
t = F^{-1}(1 - \alpha \, \vert \,\mathcal{H}_{0})
\end{equation}

$F^{-1}( \mathbf{x} \, \vert \,\mathcal{H}_{0})$ is the inverse cumulative distribution for the data $\mathbf{x}$ under the null. The Bayes threshold for the same hypothesis test that minimizes risk, under $0-1$ loss:

\begin{equation}
t = \cfrac{ C_{10} - C_{00} }{ C_{01} - C_{11} }\cfrac{ \text{Pr}(\mathcal{H}_{0}) }{ \text{Pr}(\mathcal{H}_{1}) } = \cfrac{ C_{10} - C_{00} }{ C_{01} - C_{11} }\cfrac{ \text{Pr}(\mathcal{H}_{0}) }{ 1- \text{Pr}(\mathcal{H}_{0}) }
\end{equation}

The $C_{ij}$ are the costs. The cost $C_{ij}$ is the cost if we decide that $\mathcal{H}_{i}$ is true, but $\mathcal{H}_{j}$ is true. This is the general expression, but I'll simplify it a bit more and assume correct decisions have no cost. I then equate the thresholds (maybe you'll tell me that this is philosophically contradictory):

\begin{equation}
\cfrac{ C_{10} }{ C_{01} }\cfrac{ \text{Pr}(\mathcal{H}_{0}) }{ 1- \text{Pr}(\mathcal{H}_{0}) }
 = 
F^{-1}(1 - \alpha \, \vert \,\mathcal{H}_{0})
\end{equation}

I could also operate on each side of this equation with cumulative distribution under the null, $F(\bullet \, \vert \,\mathcal{H}_{0})$, but it's just the same equation re-stated.

Why do I care about this? I would like to see if what false alarm rate I set, $\alpha$, is equivalent to a set of costs, given my priors. I just need to know if anything I have written here is B.S. for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: There is an equivalence in the sense that the frequentist decision do-not-reject or reject $H_0$ can be made equivalent in the same as the same threshold as the Bayesian decision of action $0$ or $1$ for some values of $\alpha, C_{10},C_{01},\Pr( H_0)$, at least where the two hypotheses are simple.

Comment: But they are not in a sense a meaningful equivalence, since the frequentist decision does not take $C_{10},C_{01},\Pr(H_0)$ into account in setting the threshold and the Bayesian decision does not treat $\alpha$ as part of the decision rule. 
If you were to move to a composite alternative hypothesis, such as $\mu\not = 0$, the frequentist might still have a threshold, while the Bayesian might believe that this had probability $1$ making the Bayesian decision almost always action $1$.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, Henry.